# matplotlib x label placement

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to create a chart as follows. And need to display dates in x axis like in the image.

[image]

But i was only able to generate a chart like following. 
[image]

Please see the code that use to generate this chart

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()            
ax.plot(numpyTradeData.date, numpyTradeData.adj_close)

#Add Text in Grap
ax.text(0.5,0.1, 'Class Period\n %s - %s'%(clsStartPeriod.strftime('%B %d, 
%Y'),clsEndPeriod.strftime('%B %d, %Y')),
horizontalalignment='center',
fontsize=9, color='red',
transform=ax.transAxes)

#Fill An Area in Graph
ax.fill_between(numpyTradeData.date[classStartPeriodIndex:classEndPeriodIndex], 0, numpyTradeData.adj_close[classStartPeriodIndex:classEndPeriodIndex], facecolor='0.9', alpha='0.5')   

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(numticks=5))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dateStrFormatter)
ax.set_xlim(minDate,maxDate)
ax.set_ylabel('Share Price')

formatter = FuncFormatter(self.addDollarSymbol)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

I know i can add rotation or display labels vertically. But Couldn't figure out how to show labels like in the first image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `set_position` and `get_position` methods of tick objects.
A small example would be:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f,a = plt.subplots(1,1)
a.plot([1,2])
ticks = a.xaxis.get_ticklabels()
for tick in ticks[::2]:
    tpos = tick.get_position()
    tick.set_position((tpos[0],tpos[1]-0.05))
```

this produces
[image]
Note that the `0.05` shift is in screen dimensions.